# Zoom images on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, fancybox

On mobile devices I have images in blog posts and when user click's on image it should appear in lightbox and user should have ability to zoom this image. Found this functionality on this site http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-light-box-for-Photography/ - first image in this post. It look's like a fancybox plugin but I cannot find how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Found good plugin for this task http://photoswipe.com/